# Putting a Try and Except inside a Loop

Tags: while-loop, try-except, python-3.5

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to put a 'Try and Except' inside of a while loop. My brother challenged me to creating a program of the computer creating a random number (1-100) then the user to try and guess what it is. I managed to get this working but I am stuck on if the user didn't actually input a number, what I should do so that the program doesn't just stop working but just prompts the user in what they have done wrong. Below I have attached my full code. The program works, but I am not sure how to put the While loop in it. I have tried doing things like 'While guess != integer' and I've been looking up different ways on how I could do it. The best I've seen is someone just saying to put the try and except into a while loop, but it didn't tell me how I could do it. [try-except inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069057/try-except-inside-a-loop) . If possible I also wondered if there was anyway I could just call this loop at any point when the user answers, so if they do continuously mistype I don't need to do anything else. Thank you for taking your time to read this, sorry I wrote a lot

```
import random
import time
def guessMyNumber():
print("Hello , welcome to Guess My Number")
time.sleep(1)
print ("The computer is thinking of a number between 1-100")
time.sleep(2)
print("Try to guess the number in as few attempts as possible")
number=random.randint(1,100)
try:
    guess=int(input("Take a guess "))
except ValueError:
    print("You must enter a whole number")
    guess=int(input("Please take another guess, making sure that it is a whole number. Thank you. "))
 tries = 1
while guess !=number:
    if guess>number:
        print("You need to go lower")
        guess=int(input("Take a guess "))
    else:
        print("Go higher!")
        guess=int(input("Take a guess "))
    tries=tries+1
if tries < 5:
    print("Well done! You guessed the number in", tries, "tries! If you would like to play again please type 'guessMyNumber()'")
else:
        print("You guessed the number in", tries, "tries. If you would like to play again type 'guessMyNumber()' ")
```

guessMyNumber()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your except block should not raise exception, below is one example how you could do int and you could modify as per your program requirements

```
count = 0
while count < 5:
 try:
    guess=int(input("Take a guess "))
 except ValueError:
    print("You must enter a whole number")
    print("Please take another guess, making sure that it is a whole number. Thank you. ")
 count = count+1
```

Comment: Ah I see, so instead of the try- except only in one part I have to make all of the inputs of the user go through this process. Thank you