# How can I Bypass Error to Continue a Call Made in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, try-except

This is my first time coding and Python seems to be a pretty easy language. However, I am running into an issue.

I am getting SNS topic attributes from AWS and it returns quite a few results. It stalls and gives an internal error -- I have researched the try/except statement and so far I have been able to use it to clear the error. How do I get the script to continue after the error has been cleared?

Comment: are you running a loop? than you can use `continue`, otherwise use `pass`

Comment: @RonaldDas I am using for loop --should I use continue after except statement?
here is a sample of my try/except statement and  for loop --

`try:
    for page in client.get_paginator('list_topics').paginate():
        print('startpage')
        for topic in page.get('Topics'):
            print(topic['TopicArn'])
            print(client.get_topic_attributes(TopicArn=topic['TopicArn']))
except:
    print('Invalid due implicit deny')`

Comment: @RonaldDas please see above

Comment: your try statement should be below the for statement. 
Please see this answer for clarification https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069057/try-except-inside-a-loop